# Custom UserControl Won't show when fired by event in another project 'ClassLibrary'

Tags: c#

I have two projects, one of them is my mainApplication and another is a classLibrary, where communicates with Hardware.

In the classLibrary I have an event, which is fired when x hardware is disconnected, on my mainApplication, I add that event to custom function, where 
my custom control located on my mainApplication won't show up, but when call something like MessageBox, it shows ... Probably if I add that mainApplication to references on classLibrary it will work, but I don't want to do that.

Follow sample code

Class Library sat

```
public event ConnectedSATChanged connectionChanged;
```

MainApp

```
sat.connectionChanged += new 
SAT.SATInternalFunctions.ConnectedSATChanged(Sat_connectionChanged);    

private void Sat_connectionChanged()
{
 MessageDialog.Show("WARNING"); // Wont show Or any other custom control 
 MessageBox.Show("Warning"); // Will Show ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

The follow code made it

```
  var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
      MessageDialog.Show("Warning!");
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without adding reference you need to find a way to trigger an event in the class library. Either WCF, web server or database can be used here.

Comment: The event by it self is created already, and fired by changing a bool property on the class library, i just handle the fired event in the mainApp ... Where appears, mainApp can't show the custom control on its own code ...

Comment: @R.Lowe I understand your point but you have two separate projects, if you want to fire event in one project and handle it in another then you need to link them anyway.